# ruby on rails has_many :through association which has two columns with same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-many-through

I have the following model:

```
class UserShareTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :sharee_id, :post_id, :sharer_id

  belongs_to :sharer, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :sharee, :class_name => "User"

  validates :sharer_id, :presence => true
  validates :sharee_id, :presence => true
  validates :post_id, :presence => true
end
```

In the Post model, I have the following line:

```
has_many :user_share_tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :user_sharers, :through => :user_share_tags, :uniq => true, :class_name => "User"
has_many :user_sharees, :through => :user_share_tags, :uniq => true, :class_name => "User"
```

How do I convey that :user_sharers should correspond to :sharer_id? and :user_sharees should correspond to :sharee_id? Since they both are the same User model, I am unsure what to do.

Somewhat related problem - in the User model I have:

```
has_many :user_share_tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :user_shared_posts, :through => :user_share_tags, :uniq => true, :class_name => "Post"
has_many :recommended_posts, :through => :user_share_tags, :uniq => true, :class_name => "Post"
```

How do I incorporate the additional logic that :user_shared_posts should contain the posts where the :sharer_id is the user_id? and :recommended_posts should contain the posts where the :sharee_id is the user_id?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a `:source` parameter to your `has_many` associations (and you don't need the `:class_name` option):

```
has_many :user_sharers, :through => :user_share_tags, :source => :sharer, :uniq => true, :class_name => "User"
has_many :user_sharers, :through => :user_share_tags, :source => :sharee, :uniq => true, :class_name => "User"
```

Then in your `User` model, you need an extra `has_many` association:

```
has_many :user_share_tags_as_sharee, :class_name => "UserShareTag", :foreign_key => :sharee_id, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :user_share_tags_as_sharer, :class_name => "UserShareTag", :foreign_key => :sharer_id, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :user_shared_posts, :source => :post, :through => :user_share_tags_as_sharer, :uniq => true
has_many :recommended_posts, :source => :post, :through => :user_share_tags_as_sharee, :uniq => true
```

Comment: what does source parameter do ?