# Rails - Using multple has_many through: associations joining same two models. Redundant has_many through:

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, associations

Would association person and company through employment AND through interviewing be bad practice? 
Why, specifically? 
And does that answer apply to databases in general, not just rails?

Example:

employment.rb

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :people
    belongs_to :companies
end
```

interview.rb

```
class Interview < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :people
    belongs_to :companies
end
```

person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employments
    has_many :interviews
    has_many :companies, through: :employments
    has_many :companies, through: :interviews
end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employments
    has_many :interviews
    has_many :companies, through: :employments
    has_many :companies, through: :interviews
end
```

Person and Company are associated through Employment, but also redundantly through Interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having two models having multiple associations, including multiple associations of the same type. You will want to give the associations unique names, though - otherwise when you called (for instance) `@person.companies`, you wouldn't know what you were going to get - companies through employments, or companies through interviews.

I believe this question has a decent example: [ruby on rails has_many :through association which has two columns with same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195916/ruby-on-rails-has-many-through-association-which-has-two-columns-with-same-mode)

Comment: Do you mean in one of the "joining" models, giving a pseudonym for one of the main models?

Comment: @gwho5150 I mean the 'main' models - the important thing is to avoid ambiguity when you refer to the (collections of) associated models.